# Labeling using Arcade in ArcGIS Online

Tags: labeling, arcgis-online, arcade

Advice on using Arcade to make "mimic" the capabilities of Maplex in ArcGIS Desktop or is there a template or "standard" for label placement and scale ranges using Arcade?

To specify most of the labeling concerns road centerlines and their spacing, density and conflict with other feature layers in my Web map.